# Label the actual data points in y-axis [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I have a plot with two plotting by using `yyaxis`. The grid on the right `yyaxis` is currently aligned with the left `yyaxis` according to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/671503-how-to-set-the-grid-of-the-right-yyaxis#answer_561648). Now I want to also label the actual data points on the right `yyaxis`. How can I achieve this as illustrated in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the axes `YTick` and `YTickLabel` properties. You would just need to be sure that the active side is the right one.

In your example, adding these lines would do the trick:

```
yyaxis('right');
set(gca,'YTick',[0, 2, 2.8, 5.6, 7, 8.4, 11, 11.2, 14]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yyaxis right;
yt = yticks;
addticks = [2 7 11];
yticks(sort([yt addticks]));
```